# Result returning zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure what I am missing here.

I am using the following code

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(4000)
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT InitialComment, DATEDIFF(d, InitialComment, GETDATE() ) AS Duration FROM dbo.SocialManagementTracker;'

DECLARE @newVal nvarchar(4000)
SET @newVal = ''

exec sp_executesql @sqlText, @newVal out

UPDATE dbo.SocialManagementTracker
SET DaysToResolve = @newVal
WHERE SocialID = 2
```

The dates being compared are 2018/07/08 and 2018/08/31. My result should be 23. Any reason why this returns 0 instead?

Comment: You're not assigning a value to `@newVal` within `@sqlText`, and you're also missing parameter declaration on the sp_executesql line.  @newVal should be an INT, and why are you using dynamic SQL anyway?

Comment: @DaveCullum probably a dumb question, i am very new to sql. how do i assign the value to @newVal?

Comment: What are you tying to do, I think you've gone a bit too far here... you shouldn't need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: See scsimon's answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any reason for dynamic sql here... this should work fine:

```
UPDATE dbo.SocialManagementTracker
SET DaysToResolve =  DATEDIFF(day, InitialComment, GETDATE() )
WHERE SocialID = 2
```

Comment: I would add a callout to this excellent answer. Notice he used "DATEDIFF(day" instead of the shorthand "DATEDIFF(d"? The shorthand stuff can be incredibly confusing and it is generally preferred to use the full name. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 1):

You can simply the complete query in single update query like below.

```
UPDATE dbo.SocialManagementTracker
SET DaysToResolve = DATEDIFF(d, InitialComment, GETDATE() )
WHERE SocialID = 2
```

Comment: You got it! I think you will [**enjoy this blog regarding shorthand in date functions**](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)